# How to set Kinect avatar origin axes?

Tags: c#, xna, kinect, xna-4.0, kinect-sdk

I am developing a Kinect Project with XNA Frameworks. I want to keep the avatar stable on the origin axes to see like on the floor in real world. I changed the bone transformation axes but I couldn't get any positive progress.

Here is the bone transformtion code block:

```
private void SetJointTransformation(BoneOrientation bone, Skeleton skeleton, Matrix bindRoot, ref Matrix[] boneTransforms)
{
    // Always look at the skeleton root
    if (bone.StartJoint == JointType.HipCenter && bone.EndJoint == JointType.HipCenter)
    {
        // Unless in seated mode, the hip center is special - it is the root of the NuiSkeleton and describes the skeleton orientation in the world
        // (camera) coordinate system. All other bones/joint orientations in the hierarchy have hip center as one of their parents.
        // However, if in seated mode, the shoulder center then holds the skeleton orientation in the world (camera) coordinate system.
        bindRoot.Translation = Vector3.Zero;
        Matrix invBindRoot = Matrix.Invert(bindRoot);

        Matrix hipOrientation = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);

        // Here we create a rotation matrix for the hips from the inverse of the bind pose
        // for the pelvis rotation and the inverse of the bind pose for the root node (0) in the Dude model.
        // This multiplication effectively removes the initial 90 degree rotations set in the first two model nodes.
        Matrix pelvis = boneTransforms[1];
        pelvis.Translation = Vector3.Zero; // Ensure pure rotation as we explicitly set world translation from the Kinect camera below.
        Matrix invPelvis = Matrix.Invert(pelvis);

        Matrix combined = (invBindRoot * hipOrientation) * invPelvis;

        this.ReplaceBoneMatrix(JointType.HipCenter, combined, true, ref boneTransforms);
    }
    else if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.ShoulderCenter)
    {
        // This contains an absolute rotation if we are in seated mode, or the hip center is not tracked, as the HipCenter will be identity
        if (this.chooser.SeatedMode || (this.Chooser.SeatedMode == false && skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipCenter].TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked))
        {
            bindRoot.Translation = Vector3.Zero;
            Matrix invBindRoot = Matrix.Invert(bindRoot);

            Matrix hipOrientation = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);

            // We can use the same method as in HipCenter above to invert the root and pelvis bind pose,
            // however, alternately we can also explicitly swap axes and adjust the rotations to get from
            // the Kinect rotation to the model hip orientation, similar to what we do for the following joints/bones.

            // Kinect = +X left, +Y up, +Z forward in body coordinate system
            // Avatar = +Z left, +X up, +Y forward
            Quaternion kinectRotation = KinectHelper.DecomposeMatRot(hipOrientation);    // XYZ
            Quaternion avatarRotation = new Quaternion(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // transform from Kinect to avatar coordinate system
            Matrix combined = Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(avatarRotation);

            // Add a small adjustment rotation to manually correct for the rotation in the parent bind
            // pose node in the model mesh - this can be found by looking in the FBX or in 3DSMax/Maya.
            Matrix adjustment = Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(-90));
            combined *= adjustment;
            Matrix adjustment2 = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(-90));
            combined *= adjustment2;

            // Although not strictly correct, we apply this to the hip center, as all other bones are children of this joint.
            // Application at the spine or shoulder center instead would require manually updating of the bone orientations below for the whole body to move when the shoulders twist or tilt.
            this.ReplaceBoneMatrix(JointType.HipCenter, combined, true, ref boneTransforms);
        }
    }
    else if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.Spine)
    {
        Matrix tempMat = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);

        // The Dude appears to lean back too far compared to a real person, so here we adjust this lean.
        this.CorrectBackwardsLean(skeleton, ref tempMat);

        // Also add a small constant adjustment rotation to correct for the hip center to spine bone being at a rear-tilted angle in the Kinect skeleton.
        // The dude should now look more straight ahead when avateering
        Matrix adjustment = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(20));  // 20 degree rotation around the local Kinect x axis for the spine bone.
        tempMat *= adjustment;

        // Kinect = +X left, +Y up, +Z forward in body coordinate system
        // Avatar = +Z left, +X up, +Y forward
        Quaternion kinectRotation = KinectHelper.DecomposeMatRot(tempMat);    // XYZ
        Quaternion avatarRotation = new Quaternion(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // transform from Kinect to avatar coordinate system
        tempMat = Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(avatarRotation);

        // Set the corresponding matrix in the avatar using the translation table we specified.
        // Note for the spine and shoulder center rotations, we could also try to spread the angle
        // over all the Avatar skeleton spine joints, causing a more curved back, rather than apply
        // it all to one joint, as we do here.
        this.ReplaceBoneMatrix(bone.EndJoint, tempMat, false, ref boneTransforms);
    }
    else if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.Head)
    {
        Matrix tempMat = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);

        // Add a small adjustment rotation to correct for the avatar skeleton head bones being defined pointing looking slightly down, not vertical.
        // The dude should now look more straight ahead when avateering
        Matrix adjustment = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(-30));  // -30 degree rotation around the local Kinect x axis for the head bone.
        tempMat *= adjustment;

        // Kinect = +X left, +Y up, +Z forward in body coordinate system
        // Avatar = +Z left, +X up, +Y forward
        Quaternion kinectRotation = KinectHelper.DecomposeMatRot(tempMat);    // XYZ
        Quaternion avatarRotation = new Quaternion(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // transform from Kinect to avatar coordinate system
        tempMat = Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(avatarRotation);

        // Set the corresponding matrix in the avatar using the translation table we specified
        this.ReplaceBoneMatrix(bone.EndJoint, tempMat, false, ref boneTransforms);
    }
    else if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.ElbowLeft || bone.EndJoint == JointType.WristLeft)
    {
        Matrix tempMat = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);

        if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.ElbowLeft)
        {
            // Add a small adjustment rotation to correct for the avatar skeleton shoulder/upper arm bones.
            // The dude should now be able to have arms correctly down at his sides when avateering
            Matrix adjustment = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(-15));  // -15 degree rotation around the local Kinect z axis for the upper arm bone.
            tempMat *= adjustment;
        }

        // Kinect = +Y along arm, +X down, +Z forward in body coordinate system
        // Avatar = +X along arm, +Y down, +Z backwards
        Quaternion kinectRotation = KinectHelper.DecomposeMatRot(tempMat);    // XYZ
        Quaternion avatarRotation = new Quaternion(kinectRotation.Y, -kinectRotation.Z, -kinectRotation.X, kinectRotation.W); // transform from Kinect to avatar coordinate system
        tempMat = Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(avatarRotation);

        this.ReplaceBoneMatrix(bone.EndJoint, tempMat, false, ref boneTransforms);
    }
    else if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.HandLeft)
    {
        Matrix tempMat = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);

        // Add a small adjustment rotation to correct for the avatar skeleton wist/hand bone.
        // The dude should now have the palm of his hands toward his body when arms are straight down
        Matrix adjustment = Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(-90));  // -90 degree rotation around the local Kinect y axis for the wrist-hand bone.
        tempMat *= adjustment;

        // Kinect = +Y along arm, +X down, +Z forward in body coordinate system
        // Avatar = +X along arm, +Y down, +Z backwards
        Quaternion kinectRotation = KinectHelper.DecomposeMatRot(tempMat);    // XYZ
        Quaternion avatarRotation = new Quaternion(0.0f, 0.0f, -kinectRotation.Z, kinectRotation.W);
        tempMat = Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(avatarRotation);

        this.ReplaceBoneMatrix(bone.EndJoint, tempMat, false, ref boneTransforms);
    }
    else if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.ElbowRight || bone.EndJoint == JointType.WristRight)
    {
        Matrix tempMat = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);

        if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.ElbowRight)
        {
            // Add a small adjustment rotation to correct for the avatar skeleton shoulder/upper arm bones.
            // The dude should now be able to have arms correctly down at his sides when avateering
            Matrix adjustment = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(15));  // 15 degree rotation around the local Kinect  z axis for the upper arm bone.
            tempMat *= adjustment;
        }

        // Kinect = +Y along arm, +X up, +Z forward in body coordinate system
        // Avatar = +X along arm, +Y back, +Z down
        Quaternion kinectRotation = KinectHelper.DecomposeMatRot(tempMat);    // XYZ
        Quaternion avatarRotation = new Quaternion(kinectRotation.Y, -kinectRotation.Z, -kinectRotation.X, kinectRotation.W); // transform from Kinect to avatar coordinate system
        tempMat = Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(avatarRotation);

        this.ReplaceBoneMatrix(bone.EndJoint, tempMat, false, ref boneTransforms);
    }
    else if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.HandRight)
    {
        Matrix tempMat = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);

        // Add a small adjustment rotation to correct for the avatar skeleton wist/hand bone.
        // The dude should now have the palm of his hands toward his body when arms are straight down
        Matrix adjustment = Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(90));  // -90 degree rotation around the local Kinect y axis for the wrist-hand bone.
        tempMat *= adjustment;

        // Kinect = +Y along arm, +X up, +Z forward in body coordinate system
        // Avatar = +X along arm, +Y down, +Z forwards
        Quaternion kinectRotation = KinectHelper.DecomposeMatRot(tempMat);    // XYZ
        Quaternion avatarRotation = new Quaternion(kinectRotation.Y, -kinectRotation.X, kinectRotation.Z, kinectRotation.W); // transform from Kinect to avatar coordinate system
        tempMat = Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(avatarRotation);

        this.ReplaceBoneMatrix(bone.EndJoint, tempMat, false, ref boneTransforms);
    }
    else if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.KneeLeft)
    {
        // Combine the two joint rotations from the hip and knee
        Matrix hipLeft = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(skeleton.BoneOrientations[JointType.HipLeft].HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);
        Matrix kneeLeft = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);
        Matrix combined = kneeLeft * hipLeft;

        this.SetLegMatrix(bone.EndJoint, combined, ref boneTransforms);
    }
    else if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.AnkleLeft || bone.EndJoint == JointType.AnkleRight)
    {
        Matrix tempMat = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);
        this.SetLegMatrix(bone.EndJoint, tempMat, ref boneTransforms);
    }
    else if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.KneeRight)
    {
        // Combine the two joint rotations from the hip and knee
        Matrix hipRight = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(skeleton.BoneOrientations[JointType.HipRight].HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);
        Matrix kneeRight = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);
        Matrix combined = kneeRight * hipRight;

        this.SetLegMatrix(bone.EndJoint, combined, ref boneTransforms);
    }
    else if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.FootLeft || bone.EndJoint == JointType.FootRight)
    {
        // Only set this if we actually have a good track on this and the parent
        if (skeleton.Joints[bone.EndJoint].TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked && skeleton.Joints[skeleton.BoneOrientations[bone.EndJoint].StartJoint].TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
        {
            Matrix tempMat = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);

            // Add a small adjustment rotation to correct for the avatar skeleton foot bones being defined pointing down at 45 degrees, not horizontal
            Matrix adjustment = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(-45));
            tempMat *= adjustment;

            // Kinect = +Y along foot (fwd), +Z up, +X right in body coordinate system
            // Avatar = +X along foot (fwd), +Y up, +Z right
            Quaternion kinectRotation = KinectHelper.DecomposeMatRot(tempMat); // XYZ
            Quaternion avatarRotation = new Quaternion(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // transform from Kinect to avatar coordinate system
            tempMat = Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(avatarRotation);

            this.ReplaceBoneMatrix(bone.EndJoint, tempMat, false, ref boneTransforms);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to keep the avatar on the origin?

Comment: Do you want the model to be stable for translations, for rotations or both?

Comment: both translation and rotation

Comment: What happens if you remove the line `this.ReplaceBoneMatrix(JointType.HipCenter, combined, true, ref boneTransforms);`
?

Comment: Pardon , the avatar mirroring is cancelled and see the only backward of avatar.

Comment: But, at least you do have no more rotation of the entire body, don't you?

Comment: not completely but much better.Actually I want to keep stable on the origin , always keep in the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the body is defined in:

```
if (bone.StartJoint == JointType.HipCenter && bone.EndJoint == JointType.HipCenter)
{
    // Unless in seated mode, the hip center is special - it is the root of the NuiSkeleton and describes the skeleton orientation in the world
    // (camera) coordinate system. All other bones/joint orientations in the hierarchy have hip center as one of their parents.
    // However, if in seated mode, the shoulder center then holds the skeleton orientation in the world (camera) coordinate system.
    bindRoot.Translation = Vector3.Zero;
    Matrix invBindRoot = Matrix.Invert(bindRoot);

    Matrix hipOrientation = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);

    // Here we create a rotation matrix for the hips from the inverse of the bind pose
    // for the pelvis rotation and the inverse of the bind pose for the root node (0) in the Dude model.
    // This multiplication effectively removes the initial 90 degree rotations set in the first two model nodes.
    Matrix pelvis = boneTransforms[1];
    pelvis.Translation = Vector3.Zero; // Ensure pure rotation as we explicitly set world translation from the Kinect camera below.
    Matrix invPelvis = Matrix.Invert(pelvis);

    Matrix combined = (invBindRoot * hipOrientation) * invPelvis;

    this.ReplaceBoneMatrix(JointType.HipCenter, combined, true, ref boneTransforms);
}
```

You should be able to ignore the rotation of the body ignoring `hipOrientation`. However if you want the avatar to turn back when the user turn back, you have to check the orientation of the body and set the avatar's orientation accordingly.

```
if (bone.StartJoint == JointType.HipCenter && bone.EndJoint == JointType.HipCenter)
{
    bindRoot.Translation = Vector3.Zero;
    Matrix invBindRoot = Matrix.Invert(bindRoot);

    // Gets the orientation of the body
    Matrix hipOrientation = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);
    if (Vector3.DotProduct(hipOrientation.Forward, Vector3.Forward) > 0) // Checks if the body is forward or backward
        hipOrientation = Matrix.Identity; // Fix the avatar orientation to a specific forward position
    else
        hipOrientation = Matrix.CreateRotationX(Math.PI); // Fix the avatar orientation to a specific backward position

    Matrix pelvis = boneTransforms[1];
    pelvis.Translation = Vector3.Zero;
    Matrix invPelvis = Matrix.Invert(pelvis);

    Matrix combined = (invBindRoot * hipOrientation) * invPelvis;

    this.ReplaceBoneMatrix(JointType.HipCenter, combined, true, ref boneTransforms);
}
```

Maybe you should also try deleting the line:

```
pelvis.Translation = Vector3.Zero;
```

Comment: Thaks for your reply but as I said , only the backward of the avatar is seen.With your edited code , mirroring has lost and I dont no why

Comment: Is it mirrored or rotated by 180?

Comment: You should play a bit with the `bindRoot` `Matrix` to get the transform you want. For example `bindRoot = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Math.PI)`.

Comment: I have tried to rotate version It works but now when the player turn the bakward , avatar not turn backward.

Comment: I thought you wanted not rotate the model?

Comment: Sorry I can't explain myself. Avatar can rotate around itself , but move only the origin.

Comment: "but move only the origin" ?!
OK, here are the possibilities:
 1) Avatar can rotate around the Up axis.
 2) Avatar can rotate around the Right axis.
 3) Avatar can rotate around the Forward axis.
 A) Avatar can translate along the Up axis.
 B) Avatar can translate along the Right axis.
 C) Avatar can translate along the Forward axis.

What can it do?

Comment: Avatar can turn back when player turn back but it will be gravel in a single point.Avatar should can do these.

Comment: OK, I've edited my post. It might not work directly because I don't know the coordinate system used. You may have to change `Forward` to `Right` or `Up`, `>` to `<`, `CreateRotationX` to `CreateRotationY` or `CreateRotationZ`.

Comment: Thanks for editing your post . I apply your changes my program and orient the rotations, but still avatar dont turn back . Is there any posibility the kinect not detect the player turns of the players back?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. The Kinect uses "very simple" feature detection for detecting the skeleton in real time and it uses only the depth sensor for that task. I think, the depth sensor is not precise enough to distinguish front from back.

Comment: Can I cancel all rotate and depth operations?